# Почему не прокручивается страница в QWebView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebengineview

Использую *PyQt4* и `QWebView`. Есть простой код, который открывает страницу в Интернете:

```
import sys
import PyQt4
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Vertical, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
web.load(QUrl("link"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Я хочу скрыть скролл-бар прокрутки контента на странице. 
Для этого использую:

```
eb.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Vertical, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
```

Полоса прокрутки исчезает, но вместе с тем становится невозможно скроллить саму страницу. 
Что не так в коде?

Запуск кода, ниже приведенного, с *PyQt5* не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, потому, что тестирую на *Mac OS* через *Wine*. Но, что странно, скрипт с *PyQt4*, запущенный таким способом, работает нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использую PyQt5, все работает как правильно.

Удалите полосу прокрутки, ShowScrollBars, добавьте для 5.10

```
import sys

#from PyQt4.QtCore import *
#from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
#from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

#from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()                          # QWebView()

web.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.ShowScrollBars, False)    # <---

web.load(QUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1022227/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-qwebview"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу использовать PyQt5, так как он не работает на моем компьютере.

Comment: @Xyanight посмотрите некоторые посты, может чем-то поможет:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028183/set-parameters-of-screenshot-taken-by-python/20036297#20036297 и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903375/screenshot-of-multiple-webpages-in-a-headerless-qtwebkit-browser-in-python

Comment: @Xyanight, `pip install pyqt5`?

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос. PyQt5 просто не работает.